# Removing projects from Visual Studio's Task List

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, todo

When working on a project in VS, I like to use the Task List window to see the TODO's. However, it presents the TODO's for all the projects in the solution. Is it possible to isolate a particular project so you can hone in on one project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the task list, there's a column 'Project'. Hover over the column header, click the filter icon that appears, and exclude the projects you don't want. [image: Here's the filter icon.]